# Xpath PHP, Исключение (Отбор)

Tags: php, xpath

Есть xml

```
<param name="Артикул"></param>
<param name="Возраст" id="22641" valueid=""></param>
<param name="Комплектация" id="22642"></param>
<param name="Дополнительные характеристики" id="22643"></param>
<param name="Размер упаковки" id="22644"></param>
```

Есть Xpath

```
    $param_value     = $node->xpath('//param/@name');
    $param_name    = $node->xpath('//param');
    $param_id    = $node->xpath('//param/@id');
```

Не могу добиться чтобы `<param name="Артикул"></param>` игнорировался так-как там нет ID. Есть советы или примеры?

Comment: foreach ($param_id as $value) 
  { 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO oc_attribute (attribute_id, attribute_group_id, sort_order)
  VALUES ('$value', '300000', '0')";
  if ($db_opencart->query($sql) === TRUE) { } else { }
  } 

  $index = 0;
  foreach($param_id as $value2) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO oc_attribute_description (attribute_id, language_id, name)
  VALUES ('$value2', '1', '$param_name[$index]')";
  if ($db_opencart->query($sql) === TRUE) { } else { }
  $index++;
  }

Comment: Это код добавления в БД, получается что записи сдвигаются((((((

Answer (score 0):

Используй проверку на существование атрибута у тега `//tag[@attribute]`:

```
$param_value     = $node->xpath('//param[@id]/@name');
$param_name    = $node->xpath('//param[@id]');
$param_id    = $node->xpath('//param/@id');
```

Да, для `$param_id` проверка не нужна,  т.к. уже возвращает атрибут из узла только в том случае, если атрибут существует.